# Django login user never come true

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, user-input

I am having problems with my Django login.

The below if statement (if user is not None:) always resolves as false, so it moves onto the else.

I'm not sure why and I would appreciate any help

Thanks

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'post':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index.html')
            
        else:
            messages.success(request,("there is an error....")) 
            return redirect('login')
  
    else:
        return render (request ,'login.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login_user', views.login_user ,name= 'login'),
      
]
```

main urls.py

""

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from availability import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('availability.urls'), name='index'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),


]
```

'''

And here is the login form:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name='username' placeholder="username">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name='password' placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I'm trying to create a custom login form. Below is what I have so far. My issues is that no matter what I do the login never authenticates. Even tho I have the correct email and password I always get:

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom login form. My issue is that no matter what I do the login never authenticates. Even tho It have the correct username and password I always return me to login page

Comment: When you submit the form, and put a breakpoint on your `login_user` function, what does the `request.method` value equal? "post" or "POST" ?

Comment: as @jarad already outlined your if condition checks for a string, thus it is case-sensitive and will never evaluates to True because it should be 'POST'

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official documentation, the string representation of the request method is [guaranteed to be uppercase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method).

Thus, you will have to change your if statement to

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # Change here

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index.html')
            
        else:
            messages.success(request,("there is an error....")) 
            return redirect('login')
  
    else:
        return render (request ,'login.html', {})
```